# Is Newton's Gravitational Constant G a force?

Tags: newton, gravity

The Constant of Gravitation $G$ was first defined by [Boys](https://Boys,%20C.%20Vernon%20(1894).%20%22On%20the%20Newtonian%20constant%20of%20gravitation%22.%20Nature.%2050%20(1292):%20330%E2%80%93334.) in 1894:

> Employing the C.G.S system of measurement, the Newtonian Constant is equal to the force of attraction in dynes between two balls weighing a gramme each, with their centers one centimeter apart.

> [...] as soon as all the quantities but G in Newton’s equation

$$
\text{Force}=G \frac{\text{Mass} \times \text{Mass}}{\text{Distance}^2}
$$

> are known, no matter in what units the quantities are measured, G is known.

Boys says that, $G$ equals the force of attraction but when I look at the equation, I see that there is a force term, the force of attraction must be given by $F$ not by $G$.

If $G$ were equal to the force of attraction between unit Masses $M = M = 1$ gr, in unit distance $D=1$ cm, then for $2D=2$ cm, the force of attraction will be $2G$ which I believe is not correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are correct.  $G$ by itself does not have the units of force.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks, I didn't think in terms of units. But Boys, in clear terms, defines G as a force with the unit of force dynes: "the Newtonian Constant is equal to the force of attraction in dynes..." Obviously this makes the units of the gravitation equation mismatch. It appears that sometimes after Boys, physicists added to G the $m^2/kg^2$ part exactly for this reason, to make the units agree. Do you know when this change occurred?

Comment: It looks like G is a scaling factor for force.

Comment: Boys probably meant _numerically_ equal. It's not uncommon for technical authors to write loosely.

Comment: Boys also wrote: "G represents that mighty principle under the influence of which every star, planet and satellite in the universe pursues its alloted course..." What is the "mighty principle" that holds planets and satellites in orbit? It is force, right? G may or not be force, but for Boys it is force.

Comment: Also if G is not force, what is it?

Comment: Boys describes G as force, according to Boys, G has all the properties of force: «Unlike any other known physical influence, [G] is independent of medium, it knows no refraction, it cannot cast a shadow.»

Comment: More from Boys: «[G] is a mysterious power, which no man can explain; of its propagation through space, all men are ignorant.» These quotes, proves that for Boys Newtonian Force of attraction $\equiv$ G

Answer (score 3):

$G$ can't be a force for a number of reasons:

- It doesn't have the unit of a force.
- It's a plain number, while a force is a vector.
- It's constant, while a force can vary.

The way I understand the original text is that, in a very specific set of units, for very specific values of the parameters, the norm of the gravitational force happens to have the same numerical value as $G$.

But since both quantities don't have the same dimension, this equality is nothing more than a coincidence, one that will disappear as soon as you switch to other units.

There's one other example of this that I know of. When studying chemical equilibrium, the *activity* of a substance is a dimensionless number. For a compound in a solution, it's defined as:

$$a=\frac{C}{C^0}$$

$C$ being the concentration of the compound and $C^0=1~\text{mol/L}$ the standard concentration.

As the customary unit for concentration is mol/L, the activity happens to have the same numerical value as the concentration, although their respective units differ. But you cannot say that $a$ "is a concentration", because if you use other units, like mol/m$^3$ or mmol/L, it stops being true.

Comment: It does have units of force + [some other units]. Dyne is the unit of force: $G=6.674E{-8} \; dyne \ [cm^2/gram^2]$

Comment: If there is "some other units", then no, it doesn't have the same dimension as a force.

Comment: The problem is, Boys in 1894, defines G as force and gives it the unit "dyne": "Newtonian Constant is equal to the force of attraction in dynes..." But later, it seems, $cm^2/gram^2$ is added.

Comment: See my answer above. It can happen that two quantity numerically coincide with a specific choice of units, that doesn't make them of the same nature.

Comment: I think your answer needs more explaining, I don't understand it. But, Boys seems to say this, for $M=M=1$ and $D=1$, then, $F=G$ since, $F=(G\cdot 1\cdot 1)/1$

Comment: @zeynel -- I suggest you are reading more out of Boys' statement than he wrote. I see no definition of G as a force. Anyhow, it's notorious that G measures the acceleration due to gravity. Acceleration in this context can be force per unit mass.

Comment: @zeynel When you're writing things like $D=1$, it's technically incorrect because $D$ has a dimension while 1 hasn't. However, you see this sort of thing in books, when authors assume that the reader knows enough science to understand it. $D=1$ means: "I'm choosing specific units where $D$ happens to have a numerical value of 1." Anything following that totally depends on that choice of units.

Comment: @Miyase My mistake. These should be written with units as $M=M= 1$ gr and $D=1$ cm. That's how I had them in my question. And Boys writes them with units too.

Comment: @terry-s Thanks for commenting, I enjoyed reading some of your answers regarding Newton. In this case, Boys' meaning leaves no room for interpretation, he defines without any doubt that G is force: "the Newtonian Constant is equal to the force of attraction in dynes..." How else can you read "the Newtonian constant is equal to the force of attraction"? And he ascribes to G the unit of force dyne. No other meaning can be extracted from Boys' sentence, I believe.

Comment: @terry-s I don't understand this: "Anyhow, it's notorious that G measures the acceleration due to gravity. Acceleration in this context can be force per unit mass." Boys also says clearly that G is not the same thing as g. How does G measure the acceleration due to gravity? There is this definition of $G=gR^2/M$ but as far as I can tell, computing G from different values of g still gives the same value for G, because I think, R proportionately increases as g diminishes.

Comment: @zeynel : thanks. To answer your question 'how else can you read...' (the passage under discussion), I would read it as implying "The Newtonian constant is _numerically_ equal to the force of attraction in dynes [in the given situation with the given masses and distances]." I appreciate that this might seem a loose statement and unsatisfactory to those who observe strictly the discipline of regarding statements of dimensional units as if an integral part of a number that describes some physical quantity. But I believe this is a relatively modern habit and discipline, & Boys lived >100 yrs ago.

Comment: @zeynel : thanks also for your second comment. I guess I'm guilty of writing loosely here too. All I meant was that g and G are both -- in their slightly different ways -- measures of the acceleration due to gravity. G is more general and requires to be scaled by the inverse square distance and the mass -- in fact precisely by the relation that you quoted, if it is only rearranged to g = GM/R^2 .

Comment: @terry-s Is this what you mean Boys is saying: $6.67E-11=6.67E-11\times 1 \times 1  /  1^2$

Comment: @zeynel : Yes, I think that's it, assuming that it's appreciated that this is not just about bare numbers, it's a mode of explanation to help the reader to grasp mentally a concrete set of the involved quantities, and then scale them to other sizes. FWIW, when I was first taught physics, quite a long time ago now, I recall it was fairly common to hear standard physical constants explained -- (if that can still be the right word) -- by such imaginary physical setups, in which all of the auxiliary factors were 1 unit of some relevant measure.

Answer (score 2):

This is a supplement to @Miyase's answer.

**(a)** To the question in the headline, "Is Newton's Gravitational Constant G a force?" : No, as @Miyase already said, it isn't. It's a constant of proportionality.

In the OP's comments to this question there are several quotations taken from CV Boys' 1894 evening lecture at the Royal Institution, appearing to suggest something deep or mysterious about the constant of proportionality 'G'.

This can usefully be compared with opinions about other constants of proportionality, e.g. at (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110297/what-is-a-proportionality-constant-plancks-constant/):

> "There is no deep physical meaning to Boltzmann's constant. It is
> merely a conversion factor to allow us to go between [temperature  and
> energy]."

Similar views have been expressed about other named constants. Correspondingly, the constant G in the gravitational equation is just a conversion factor allowing us to go from one of several combinations of variables for mass and distance, to force, or to acceleration, &c, depending on how the equation is rearranged.

Such straightforward explanations for constants of proportionality make the statements from Boys look like theatrical mystery-making in comparison.

Also, to respond about a passage from Boys (1894) quoted and queried in the question/comments:

> "The Newtonian Constant is equal to the force of attraction in  dynes
> between two balls weighing a gramme each, with their  centers one
> centimeter apart".

This most probably meant  "The Newtonian constant is *numerically* equal to the force of attraction in dynes *in the given situation with the given masses and distance*".  It used to be a rather common way of explaining the meaning of such constants, to imagine a physical setup in which all of the auxiliary factors were 1 unit of some relevant measure. This doesn't make the constant into a force or anything else.

**(b)** The question also states that "The Constant of Gravitation G was first defined by Boys in 1894".  This appears not to be so, or at least to considerably overstate the position. What Boys did in effect was to propose a perhaps slightly new name for something much-explored and already named before him. This can be seen from [J H Poynting's historical review](https://archive.org/details/meandensityofear00poynuoft) (which won the 'Adams Prize' in 1893) which gives historical summary and explanation of much previous work. It also includes (p.2) the statement (without any claim that it was anything new)

> "... the law is general, ... if we have any two bodies, of  masses
> $M_1$ and $M_2$, $d$ apart, the force on either is
> $$  G \frac{M_1 \times M_2}{d^2} , $$
> where G is a constant, the constant of gravitation."

**(c)** The question also asks 'what am I missing' about a numerical example. The answer seems to be, that the numbers in the question unfortunately have   arithmetic/mathematical errors. If the attractive force, considered as in the question, is between 1-gram masses at a distance D of 1 cm apart, then putting '2D = 2 cm' makes no difference because D itself is then still just 1 cm. If the question meant to ask what is the attraction if D is doubled to 2 cm, then application of the inverse-square relation (1/Distance^2) shows that the attractive force is then diminished to a quarter of what it was for D = 1 cm.

**(d)** More generally, the question and the OP's comments take C V Boys seriously as a source for a number of statements given in his 1894 evening lecture at the Royal Institution [p.353-377 in their 'Proceedings' Vol.14](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZrloHemOmUEC&pg=PA353&redir_esc=y), although they were outside his field of expertise as an experimenter. Boys was indeed an experimental physicist of repute, as well as a popularizer of science. On the details of the physical measurements described in the lecture I have nothing to raise except the point that that like some others before and since, Boys exaggerated the accuracy of his results: he claimed (p.376) to be correct within 1 or 2 units in the 4th significant digit. Comparison with the [modern measure (via NIST, 2019)](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?bg)) shows that really he had only 2 significant digits right. But a reading of the lecture also shows signs that he spoke unreliably or carelessly on some other matters, including exaggeration of the degree of novelty in his experiments, and he also made substantial mis-statements about the science of gravitation. At one point he also inserted a disparaging/abusive remark about an associate! These are not things one expects to read in a serious scientific contribution.

The wrong statements about gravitational science are significant because they have misled many in the past and may probably continue to do so. Boys opened the lecture relied on by the OP with the *canard* that Newton's law of gravitation  just accounts for, or results from adoption of, Kepler's laws. The same sort of mis-statement was also carelessly adopted by some others of Boys' generation, including the influential physicist and philosopher of science Pierre Duhem (1906).  Some 19th-/20th/-21st-century writers have been  more careful, including Rouse Ball (1893), Cohen (1980) and Ducheyne (2012). Ducheyne, in particular, discussed and refuted the fallacious critique by Duhem (1906) (who used a similar  mis-statement as Boys), understandably calling such treatments "straightforwardly embarrassing". This underlines that the OP chose a source here that was unreliable at least outside a particular topic, and that to rely on an erroneous starting-point paves the way towards erroneous conclusions.

References (other than those with links above):

W W Rouse Ball (1893), ["An Essay on Newton's Principia"](https://archive.org/details/anessayonnewton01ballgoog).

P M M Duhem (1906), ["La théorie physique : son objet et sa structure"](https://archive.org/details/lathoriephysiq00duhe).

I B Cohen (1980), "The Newtonian Revolution",

S Ducheyne (2012), ["The Main Business of Natural Philosophy"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-007-2126-5).